# Prevent sending over 500 emails

Tags: php, email

```
$t_email = explode(", ", $list);
$sentEmails = count($t_email);
updateEmail($sentEmails);
for ($i = 0; $i < (count($t_email)); $i = $i + 1) {
    if(sentQueue <= 500) {
        if (mail($t_email[$i], $subject, $body, $headers)) {
            $err .= "<span class='success'>Message successfully sent to " . $t_email[$i] . "</span><br />";
        } else {
            $err .= "<span class='fail'>Message failed to be sent to " . $t_email[$i] . "</span><br />";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<span class='fail'>Sent over 500 emails. Please wait until the hour is up.</span>";
    }
}
```

And after the for loop I have this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emailLimit");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $later = $row['hourLater'];
        $sent = $row['sentEmails'];
        if ($sent == 500) {
            echo "Sent all available emails for this hour.<br/>";
        }
        else if ($timeNow > $later || $sent == 0) {
            mysql_query("UPDATE `emailLimit` SET hourLater = '$hourLater', sentEmails = '0'") or die(mysql_error());
        } else {
            echo "<h4><span class='header'>$sent/500 emails sent.  " . RelativeTime(($later)) . " remain in the hour.</span></h4>";

        }
    }
```

sentQueue function

```
function sentQueue() {
    $q = "select * from emailLimit";
    $result = mysql_query($q);
    $dbarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return $dbarray["sentEmails"];
}
```

EDIT: forgot to post

```
function updateEmail($vp) {
        $q = "select * from emailLimit";
        $result = mysql_query($q);
        $dbarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $vp = $vp + $dbarray["sentEmails"];
        $q = "update emailLimit set sentEmails = '$vp'";
        mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

When I send emails to my mailing list I still can go over 500 emails. It doesn't stop. How can I make it so it completely stops sending mail if it hits 500? Or log the emails that go over 500 so I can email them back after the hour is over? (My host is limited to 500 per hour).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Fyi, there's `$i++;` and also `foreach($array as $key => $value)` in PHP

Comment: do you need brackets after the sentQueue reference on the fifth line? and do you need to update the database to the new number of sent emails?

Comment: @Thief thanks
@lee it's not the full code its just a copy & paste

Comment: I understand, however I thought that all references to functions needed brackets after them.

Comment: Why risk getting your ISP mad or worse yet getting your domain blacklisted? There is a reason they have a 500 email per hour limit. http://www.mailchimp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem I wasn't calling the function silly me. `if(sentQueue() <= 500) {`

Fixed now.